# python2.5 says platform dependent libraries not found

Tags: python, configuration

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Aug  8 2009, 17:18:03)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> import operator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named operator
```

Comment: Do you have any PYTHON* environment variables set (do "env | grep PYTHON")?  If so, try unsetting them.

Comment: I checked the environment there is nothing set, Its CentOS 5.3

Comment: What's the value of sys.path ("import sys; sys.path")?

Comment: >>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python25.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages']

Comment: Notice how re imported fine. Where did you get this distribution of Python? I would uninstall and and reinstall a version from python.org.

Comment: re is a pure python module.  You should see it in /usr/local/lib/python25{,.zip}.  operator is a C module; it should be in /usr/local/lib/lib-dynload.  If not, your installation is faulty and, yes, you should reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module `operator` should come from file `operator.so`, presumably in `/usr/local/lib/lib-dynload` in your case since that seems to be where you've installed things. So what .so files are in that directory?

Assuming operator.so is indeed missing (i.e., assuming it's not some trivial case of wrong permissions on some directory or file) the best way to "get it back" is no doubt, as a comment already suggested, to reinstall Python 2.5 (assuming you need that release e.g. to work with app engine) from either an official Python package at python.org, or an official CentOS 5.3 one (if one exists -- I believe CentOS 5.3 uses Python 2.4 as the official /usr/bin/python but there may be RPMs to place 2.5 somewhere else).

Comment: yes I have tried to install python2.5 form python.org it was successfully installed, and lib-dynload was used in python2.4 for python2.5 FILE (built-in)

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the /usr/local/bin/python file and the error went away.
I suspect this was an old version of python because I have a file python2.7 in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating what I said earlier in a comment: re is a pure python module. You should see it in `/usr/local/lib/python25{,.zip}`. operator is a C module; it should be in `/usr/local/lib/lib-dynload`. If not, your installation is faulty and, yes, you should reinstall.